# JMeter HTML Dashboard report not displaying in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, report, dashboard

I'm unable to view the Jmeter Dashboard report in Jenkins, however the jenkins job creates a index.html report but it's empty

[image: jenkins]

it works fine locally and index.html is generated with all the required values.

[image: local]

What am i missing over here?

here's my pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.performance.dataengg</groupId>
  <artifactId>DataEngg</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>DataEngg</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>Windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <script.extension>.bat</script.extension>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <script.extension>.sh</script.extension>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/htmlReport/Reporting_framework/</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>AggregateReport.csv</include>
                                <include>Report.html</include>
                                <include>ReportOutput.zip</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesUser>
                        <threads>${threads}</threads>
                        <rampUp>${rampUp}</rampUp>
                        <baseURL>${baseURL}</baseURL>
                        <Pconstantthroughputtimer>${constantThroughputTimer}</Pconstantthroughputtimer>
                        <Resultsdirectory>${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl</Resultsdirectory>
                        <loopCountDuration>${loopCountDuration}</loopCountDuration>

                    </propertiesUser>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run JMeter tests -->
                     <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Fail build on errors in test -->
                </executions>
            </plugin>

             <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-site</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <delete dir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard" />
                                <mkdir dir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard" />
                                <copy file="${basedir}/src/test/resources/reportgenerator.properties"
                                         tofile="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/reportgenerator.properties" />
                                <copy todir="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/report-template">
                                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/src/test/resources/report-template" />
                                </copy>
                                <java jar="${basedir}/target/jmeter/bin/ApacheJMeter-4.0.jar" fork="true">
                                    <arg value="-l" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl" />
                                    <arg value="-g" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/*.jtl" />
                                    <arg value="-o" />
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/target/jmeter/results/dashboard/" />
                                </java>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can it be some jenkins configuration that's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to Jenkins [Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-Implementation).

You need to adjust it by setting Java System Property:

> hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP

Since it contains reserved char, you can set this property by creating a [Groovy script](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post-initialization+script) file $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy, or any .groovy file in the directory $JENKINS_HOME/init.groovy.d/ containing:

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; font-src *;img-src 'self' data: *;frame-ancestors 'self'")
```

If you're looking to lean more about Performance testing and JMeter, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) can help you.

Note that you could do what your are doing easily following this [tutorial](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/shift-left-performance-tests-jmeter-maven/).

Comment: jenkins admin says the above mentioned change poses a security risk, is that true? if yes, then what's the alternate solution, can i configure the changes in jenkins job itself?

Comment: It relaxes security but ask him to explain the risk. No you can’t configure at job level. No other solution AFAIK. If answer is ok please accept it and upvote. Thanks

Comment: I tried to adjust system property by using script console at the configure node level, but it didn't worked for me. What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 2):

Since my organisation doesn't allow relaxing the security and resetting the Content Security Policy, hence i did this using `docker` and was able to view the reports cleanly

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:3.9

ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-5.1
ENV JMETER_BIN ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL http://mirrors.estointernet.in/apache//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.1.tgz

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --update openjdk8-jre curl unzip bash \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies  \
    && curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-5.1.tgz  \
    && mkdir -p /opt  \
    && tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-5.1.tgz -C /opt  \
    && rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

COPY launch.sh /opt/
COPY src/ /opt/src

WORKDIR /opt

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/launch.sh"]
```

And you can have your `jmeter` commands inside `launch.sh` and .jmx scripts inside `src` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can display the dashboard using [HTML Publisher Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTML+Publisher+Plugin)

By default [Jenkins Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) looks like

```
sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';
```

The value is being read from `hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP` [Java System property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) so you can configure it to more "relaxed" by setting the relevant value via [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) (it will live until the next restart) or by adding the relevant parameter to Jenkins startup argument.

You might also be interested in [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which adds some extra  features like pass/fail criteria and performance trends charts